# What does "straight out of" mean?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

> OP: "Mother dished the food up straight out of the saucepan"

I only know what "straight out" means. It means FRANKLY or DIRECTLY. But when it adds "of" behind it, I just cannot figure out what does it actually mean?

Comment: The sense of "frankly" that you learned is an _idiom_, based on the literal meaning "straight=direct" . (As for your second question, ask it separately; it's unrelated to your main question.)

Comment: _How cunning a man_ and _How cunning of him_ are very similar phrases, but, to answer your question, it doesn't need to be changed. _How cunning of him_ is normal, idiomatic speech. You can find several instances of this construct on [Google](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22how+*+of+him+to*)

Comment: Warning: [Rap Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMZi25Pq3T8)

Comment: So could i say something like"Maybe they didn't know how naive of them to challenge that tough guy" and does my example mean"If you think you can challenge that tough guy,then you are so naive"?

Answer (score 1):

It still means directly. The phrase means the food is being moved directly from the saucepan. The "of" is necessary because it indicates where the food is coming from. It links the action (removing food) to the saucepan. Without it, the sentence would simply state that the food was being removed directly... and then say "the saucepan" without linking the ideas.

This could be written in other, perhaps smoother, forms:

> Mother dished the food up straight from the saucepan
>
> Mother dished the food up out of the saucepan
>
> Mother dished the food up from the saucepan

The "straight" is fairly redundant in this sentence.

Comment: it also could be like"mother dished up the food straight out of the saucepan" right?

Comment: @오준수 Yes, that sounds perfectly fine as well.

Comment: In most situations,"out of" equals "from" right? i mean,when it comes to action or something like that

Comment: ahh i got it, i was considering "straight out of" a whole phrase。but actually,in such case,"straight" and "out of" should be seen as two seperate stuff.

Comment: @오준수 I'm not sure I'd say most, but I think you get the point. For describing past-tense actions, they are interchangeable. The main case I am thinking of where they would not be the same is in a command or future tense, like "get out of here!" or "I am going to get out of jail."

Comment: @오준수 Also, in vernacular, "Get out!" by itself is typically used as an expression of disbelief.